# Post preview breaks URLs with square brackets

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, markdown-rendering

The markdown editor breaks URLs that have a `[]` in them in the post preview. For example:

[Test link](http://www.example.com?array[]=item1)

the URL is:

```
http://www.example.com?array[]=item1
```

it works fine in the final result, though, so it's very minor.

Answer (score 3):

I've noticed that the URL generator (highlight your URL, then hit the world-with-arrow icon) gets confused if the URL being highlighted has a close-square-bracket -- it thinks "aha someone already put the end of URL marker in for me, so I won't bother putting in another one", which prematurely ends the URL markup:

```
link text: text
url: http://blah/foo]bar
```

becomes

```
[text]bar[1]

[1]: http://blah/foo
```

Rather than what should be:

```
[text][1]

[1]: http://blah/foo\]bar
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be minor variances in the javascript Markdown preview and the server-side Markdown rendering. This is unlikely to ever match 100%.

Comment: Not that I know which software is used to render the *Markdown*s, but couldn't one use the same context-free grammar so that, at least, the interpretation is done the same way?