# Markdown rendering URLs with spaces

Tags: support, markdown-rendering

Consider the following text

```
<code>[Collections#sort][1]</code>

[1]: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List, java.util.Comparator)
```

It does render correctly on preview, but incorrectly once saved. See [Sorting and Re-arranging List of HashMaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455448/sorting-and-re-arranging-list-of-hashmaps/2455497#2455497) for this example in real life

Comment: See also - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38261/post-preview-breaks-urls-with-square-brackets and - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23658/bug-when-encoding-links-with-underscores-in-url-fragments

Comment: Confirmed. I've tried to fix it, but to no avail.

Comment: Apparently the problem was with the url, and not with the <code></code> part. Encoding the space did the trick (see o.k.w's answer ==> http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42414/markdown-rendering-bug/42417#42417)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is the space which breaks the URL. Try the url encoded one like:
`sort(java.util.List%2C+java.util.Comparator)`
instead of
`sort(java.util.List, java.util.Comparator)`

You can also use backticks ` for inline codes.

E.g.:

Notice that, if you want to change sort algorithm during list usage, you can instead use [`Collections#sort`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List%2C+java.util.Comparator)).

Source:

```
Notice that, if you want to change sort algorithm during list usage, 
you can instead use [`Collections#sort`][1].

[1]: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List%2C+java.util.Comparator)
```

Comment: Oh, indeed, encoding the space to %20 did the trick!

Comment: @fretje, yea the 'evil' spaces...

Comment: @o.k.w:whoneedsthemanyway?

Comment: Wow, thanks for the reply and the fix in my answer (didn't even know you could do that !)

Comment: @Riduidel: see the bottom part of the faq (http://stackoverflow.com/faq): *Other people can edit my stuff?! Like Wikipedia, this site is collaboratively edited, and all edits are tracked. If you are not comfortable with the idea of your posts being edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you.*

Answer (score 1):

[As of recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60211/auto-escape-url-when-entering-with-hyperlink-button-ctrll/82263#82263), when entering a link via the button (or Ctrl-L), the characters will automatically be escaped, so this is the safest way.