# URL from code.google.com is not markdown-parsable

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, hyperlinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Markdown rendering URLs with spaces](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42414)

The following URL from [Google Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Code) does not seems to be parsable using the markdown Ajax widget used by Stack Overflow.

> http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=fr#Lhpgg-dZ4PI/timeline/trunk/src/webapp/api/scripts/sources.js&q=DefaultEventSource package:http://simile-widgets.googlecode.com&sa=N&cd=3&ct=rc&l=224

Is it my way to quote it that is bad? Or is it just to weird for an URL?

Comment: Damn, I've duplicated my own previous question about sopaces in urls (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42414/markdown-rendering-urls-with-spaces). How will i delete it now ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=fr#Lhpgg-dZ4PI/timeline/trunk/src/webapp/api/scripts/sources.js&q=DefaultEventSource%20package:http://simile-widgets.googlecode.com&sa=N&cd=3&ct=rc&l=224

I think the space in your URL is what is breaking it (understandably). If you replace it with a %20, then it appears to work for all possible markdown approaches (at least, I just tested each one).

Comment: Yup, that's the problem, alright

Comment: you must encode spaces in URLs. Generally speaking, spaces in URLs are A Bad Thing anyway.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: Not as annoying as those trailing )s in wikipedia links, which no URL parser known to man seems to get right - forcing me to manually edit them in my url bar :(