# What is it like to be a high-rep user?

Tags: discussion, reputation, fun, high-rep-users

It's been months.  Many months.  Asking some questions.  Answering many more questions.  Thanklessly editing hundreds, nay, thousands, of vague and poorly-formed posts.  Proving to all, far and wide, that you are the expert.  That you know all there is to know about your chosen field.  And finally, your hard work, your countless hours, your sleepless nights, have paid off.  You have built up a nearly peerless reputation.  You and your accomplishments are truly, as my old French teacher would have said, *for-mi-dable!*  You are rolling in the Internet Dollars, having amassed bankrolls well into the thousands.

What is it like, I wonder?  O!  I beseech you to tell me.  You, who consume crosshatched cakes; you, who unite with unicorns; you, the foremost of the freehanders; you, who prance with ponies.  **Are you embarassed that your Meta rep is higher than your SO/SF/SU rep?**<sup>*</sup>

*<sub>Because, uh, you see, I'm about to join your ranks, and I would like to know what I'm getting into...</sub>

Comment: I'm not a high rep user, but my Meta rep exceeded my SO rep in *six hours* from registering, which had been around for *sixty days*. You shouldn't feel embarrassed.

Comment: For the record, the fourth tag there was _intended_ to be `[because-whoever-invented-oh-noes-deserves-taxonomist]`.

Comment: @ccornet Links or it didn't happen.

Comment: Wow, this was supposed to be a Friday joke question, but... okay.

Comment: @rlb Well, I didn't exactly screencap the incident, but I did record the number in my profile for posterity (that's what the "6" as my location stands for). But, if there was a way to know the exact time the [8th vote on my answer here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46733/url-from-code-google-com-not-markdown-parsable/46735#46735) was made, you can use that to confirm the exact time my Meta rep exceeded my SO rep.

Comment: @pop I knew that from the tags, but I felt compelled to answer seriously, because for some strange reason having a high meta rep is seen as something bad

Comment: @rlb Pwa, I don't know why I bothered followed up on this, but I did. [Here is your link](http://imgur.com/XAsWV.png "Technically 6 hours and 38 minutes, but I round down.").

Comment: +1 for mentioning unicorns

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What is this "Stackoverflow" you're talking about? Is that some kind of sister site to Meta?

Comment: No, it's the older brother who left home early and is now some kind of success in the computer industry.

Comment: StackOverflow... sounds familiar... just can't place it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a type of programming error. And maybe something else too... maybe. @Ques Now why would it be a success? I'm sure you don't want errors in your programs.

Answer (score 8):

Why would I?

Meta is a very important part of the system, it's here to help users, debate about the engine itself, etc.

A high reputation in meta says you know how the system and the community works, you provided useful suggestions and/or bug reports, engine-enhancing scripts for everyone to enjoy, statistics, etc.

I'm proud to be a high rep meta user, the trilogy wouldn't work without it.

Comment: *you know how the system and the community works, you provided useful suggestions and/or bug reports, engine-enhancing scripts for everyone to enjoy, statistics,* pony images, waffle images, refer to meta memes on posts, *etc.*

Answer (score 7):

I always imagined it something like this

http://img198.imageshack.us/img198/3089/dafonz.jpg

Comment: AYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY!!!!!!!!

Comment: I'm not getting any more rep if this is what happens!!!!!!!

Answer (score 5):

As a more serious answer to what you meant to be a joke question :-) ...

I am near the top of the *smaller* (relative to stackoverflow) serverfault.  As I get higher I am more committed to seeing the community succeed since I am not sure serverfault has reached the critical mass yet (There seem to be good and bad days).

Although the reputation aspect is still kind of fun it means far less to me then seeing good questions and answers on serverfault since I have invested a good amount of time in effort into it. If it does fizzle out I won't consider my time wasted since those answers and questions will probably at least be archived on the internet, and I have learned from both answering and asking questions.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't call myself high-rep here on Meta, though I'm now on the first page of users. I have ~5200 on SO.

Really, Meta is totally distinct from the Trilogy. It's more about the management of the Trilogy, and right now I find that more interesting to analyze and post about than programming (although I still enjoy programming). I'm not embarrassed that I have more rep here than on SO, it just shows where my interests are.

---

At 3k, you have all the basic tools needed for participating on the site. The system is quite well-designed with respect to that. I will say, though, that it's a pretty long road to 10k from there. You definitely have to work for it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a moment of existential crisis when my Meta rep first exceeded my SO rep. That said, I got over it pretty quickly -- one reason my main SO rep is fairly stagnant is that my [primary activity there](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14048?tab=activity#tab-top) is junior janitoring these days. (And even that's more rare than it used to be.)

(Close votes and flags and edits FTW!)

I am a bit surprised to find out I'm a Meta first-pager. But that's because Meta has a *much* smaller community than SO proper.

What's it like? Well, I love looking at the flags and deletions, but that's because I'm inherently curious like that. I do look forward to, one of these years, breaking the 10K mark on SO so I can gain access to all the noise and junk that's been deleted there as well. (Too bad boat programming is, from my understanding, hard-purged ... )

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's much different than before all the points came... is it?

I mean, they're just points, right?

Answer (score 0):

It is worrysome to say the least. I long for the day when my reputation was unknown. a simple 101. When no worries were bestowed upon me except for ask and answer. Now there is closing responsibilities and editing. I cry myself to sleep thinking worrying about such posts. Those unicorns be cursed! Stop where you are now. Don't get above 2 thousand or you will regret it! Learn from the mistakes of others!

Comment: Then why don't you just ditcha all your rep by giving it out in bounties?  :)

Comment: should I stop getting rep now then?

Comment: This was really more of a joke posting, back when Meta was full of jokes @benny

Answer (score 0):

Worst Feeling of My Life.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Especially since I failed the precondition. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've been carefully bleeding off meta rep using bounties.  It's become a lot easier lately since I can add bounties to any question, rather than saving up my own unanswered questions for it.

Comment: By using bounties you're just spreading the disease!

Comment: @Earlz By the time you realize it's contagious, you've already been infected...