# Gold badge for meta participation

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request, per-site-meta

At the moment there's Quorum and Convention which encourage participation on meta and seem to be related (bronze / silver style.) However, there's no gold badge in this family - would this be a good idea to encourage more long term participation in meta?

Comment: It should be a badge of *sadness*. Because if you're on Meta that much, you really need better things to do. Yes, I realize this applies to me.

Comment: -1 **meta** is **murder**

Comment: [On high Meta rep](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49881/what-is-it-like-to-be-a-high-rep-user) (@mmyers)

Comment: @Pop Oh, hey, I guess we both qualify to actually answer that question, now, don't we?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think encouraging more meta participation is a good thing.  Adding a gold badge would complete the family of badges.   Something like **100 posts with a score of 2** might fit it nicely.  Not sure about a name.

Comment: I was thinking either that or a certain reputation score (say 2k)?

Comment: the name could be *Sigh*

Comment: IS this still going to be implemented? If only for the sake of completeness, I like it. I will probably never get it myself seeing as I had to struggle to get `convention`, but in the long run it gives me a reason to be more on meta. Right now, I feel like I don't really have a reason. There are a lot more people helping out than asking questions.

Answer (score 14):

> However, there's no gold badge in this family - would this be a good idea to encourage more long term participation in meta?

In my opinion, no. I think a gold badge would cause badge hunters to swamp Meta with content that they wouldn't be contributing if there weren't a prize to collect.

The only long-term Meta activity that I find generally support-worthy for every user is *voting*. An additional Electorate-like badge for Meta voting I would welcome.

Comment: @Pekka, I agree about the voting.  But if badge hunters with junk content were an issue for Meta, then why are the silver and bronze setup as needing 1 or 10 posts, instead of voting or some other requirement.

Comment: Ooooh, I like this idea!

Comment: Badge hunters haven't been a problem so far(AFAIK) and I think the meta-community can easily handle some bad content(if it's good content what's the problem?), However, I am very much for "an additional Electorate-like badge" so +1.

Comment: Re the first paragraph, I disagree. We did see a single case of a user and his sockpuppets successfully game Convention, but if the limit is really high, like 100, then it's going to be pretty obvious what's going on. There's just *no way* anyone can post that much quality content in a short period of time with *none* of us noticing.

Comment: @Jon it's not the egregious gaming cases I mean. I mean content that is fine and well-intentioned but... not only written for the sake of making a suggestion to improve the site. If somebody has no natural inclination to contributing on Meta, they shouldn't be encouraged to do so just to get the badge.

Comment: Well, I see your point, and I agree, but it's the same case with all the other badges, too. We want to promote editing, so we have Strunk & White and Copy Editor, for example.

Comment: I wanted to vote twice once for each para of you answer! After a little more than a year since you answered, the quality of questions on meta has gotten pretty bad.

Answer (score 6):

Quorum -> Convention -> Parliament

Comment: Quorum -> Convention -> Covenant

Comment: Quorum --> Convention --> Embarassment (I would have this badge _nine times_, by the way)

Answer (score 6):

A gold badge would complete the set and prompt more people to pay attention to meta.  But rather than just expanding the number of posts as suggested [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/77699/162102), we should also raise the score bar.  We don't want people to post a bunch of low-value stuff on meta just to hunt a badge, but we should recognize the people with steady, high-quality meta participation.

Convention is for 10 posts with score 2.  For the to-be-named gold badge, I suggest something like 20 posts with score 10 or 50 posts with score 5 -- something that boosts the number *and* the score requirements.  This is similar to the approach taken with tag badges.

Comment: withdrew my answer in light of this answer (and this answerer's fair enough comment).  Will add that perhaps it could be linked to the silver Beta badge (just a suggestion - apologies if I overstep the line in making suggestions as a relative new member).

Comment: @DamienPaul suggestions are welcome from anybody who cares enough about SE to come to meta and participate.  Your being new is not an impediment.

Comment: Oh I do care about SE (have 10 answers), but on reflection, I should probably wait until I have more time under my belt before raising opinions.