# Why can't I link to a specific method in the Java API?

Tags: bug, markdown-rendering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Links to URLs containing parentheses](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13501/links-to-urls-containing-parentheses)

I'm having trouble posting links to the Java documentation. Specifically, I'd like to link "Math.pow" to `http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double, double)`.  Even though doing something like

```
[Math.pow][1]
[1]:http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double, double)
```

works in the previewer, it doesn't display right in the final post.

None of the standard Markdown approaches seem to work:

[Math.pow][1]

[1]:http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double, double)

[Math.pow](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double, double))

[Math.pow](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double,%20double))

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double, double)

Comment: @Robert: well, not quite; I've just tried #5, #6, #7 and #8 (just now because of your link) and none of them work.  What's the deal?

Comment: Ah, misclicked! I was supposed to actually point to [this one that even is talking about the Java API](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42414/markdown-rendering-urls-with-spaces).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is entirely with the space appearing in the URL, if it's encoded with a "%20" instead of being left as a space the URL will work just fine:

[Math.pow](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double,%20double))

[Math.pow](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double,%20double))

[Math.pow](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double,%20double))

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double,%20double)

(though note the last "bare" link doesn't encode the final parenthesis)

Comment: None of your anchor links work. The page opens, but it does not scroll down to the anchor. It's not a markdown problem either; if you type in your url's directly into the browser, they won't work. The only one that seems to work is the unencoded one.

Comment: @Robert: in both Chrome and FireFox all but the last link work for me.

Comment: OK.  I guess it's a problem in IE8.